# Clear form after submit and page refresh - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, http-post

I know that the correct way to insert the data is using AJAX, but I don't mind if the page refreshes. Can anybody help me clear the form data after the page refreshes? Everything works fine, the data is being submitted to the table, and the page refreshes. But if I hit the refresh button again, it tells me that the data will be submitted ... and I don't know what to do.

```
<?php

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( $current_user->ID == 0 ) {

    } else {

        if( isset( $_POST['drop_artists'] ) ) {
            $answer = $_POST['drop_artists'];
        }else{
            $answer = $_POST['artist_name'];
        }

        $date =  current_time( 'mysql' );

           $table = "t4t5_answers";
           $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "INSERT INTO $table (user_id, post_id, info, answer, submission_date ) VALUES ( %d, %d, %s, %s, %d )", $current_user->ID, $post->ID, 'artist', $answer, $date );
            $wpdb->query($sql);

            header('Location: ' . get_bloginfo('url'));

}//if(isset($_POST['form_sub']))

?>

<form method="post" action="" id="artists-form"> 
<ul>
    <li id="categories">
        <?php 
        $args = array(
            'show_option_all'    => 'Artists',
            'hierarchical' => 1,
            'child_of' => 406,
            'order_by' => 'name',
            'name' => 'answer',
            'hide_empty' => 0
        );
        wp_dropdown_categories($args); ?>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="text" name="artist_name" value="" size="45" id="input-title"/>
<input id="submitButton" class="subput" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/229139/how-to-properly-refresh-page-after-form-action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the page is posted, use a redirect to send te user to a success page. This will make the page that was actually posted not appear in their history.

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // do stuff
    header("Location: $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]");
}
```

Note the URL for the redirect should be a full URL, not a relative one. In practice though, I haven't seen any browsers have a problem with the relative URL.

Comment: I would like the same page to be displayed. What if I get the original url and add it instead of success.php? Would that work?

Comment: Absolutely. The redirect will cause the browser to do a GET instead of a POST.

Comment: Like this? `$current_URL = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];` I just tried ... and it s still not working.

Comment: Just noticed that the redirect doesn't work where I have it. Where should it go?

Comment: It's got to be after all your processing of the POST data. Also has to be before any output to the browser. Check the documentation for the function for all the details. Based on your sample code it should work where you have it, but perhaps Wordpress is getting in the way? EDIT: make sure you have no blank lines before `<?php`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47717/discussion-between-miken32-and-ciprian)

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to your current url immediately, try this one

```
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$current_URL.'">'
```

for more details see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Comment: The code suggests he's working with Wordpress, so may not be able to alter the HTML header. Also using this method, I think, leaves the POST page in the browser history.

Answer (score 0):

Write your php code inside if(isset($_POST['submit']) and add following script below insert statement.

```
echo "  <script type='text/javascript'>
    window.location=document.location.href;
</script>";
```

Your code will look like the following:

```
global $wpdb,$post;
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( $current_user->ID == 0 )
    {

    }
    else
    {

        if( isset( $_POST['drop_artists'] ) )
        {
            $answer = $_POST['drop_artists'];
        }
        else
        {
            $answer = $_POST['artist_name'];
        }

        $date =  current_time( 'mysql' );

        $table = "t4t5_answers";
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "INSERT INTO $table (user_id, post_id, info, answer, submission_date ) VALUES ( %d, %d, %s, %s, %d )", $current_user->ID, $post->ID, 'artist', $answer, $date );
        $wpdb->query($sql);

}

 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        window.location=document.location.href;
        </script>";
}

?>

<form method="post" action="" id="artists-form"> 
<ul>
    <li id="categories">
        <?php 
            $args = array(
                'show_option_all'    => 'Artists',
                'hierarchical' => 1,
                'child_of' => 406,
                'order_by' => 'name',
                'name' => 'answer',
                'hide_empty' => 0
        );
        wp_dropdown_categories($args); ?>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="text" name="artist_name" value="" size="45" id="input-title"/>
<input id="submitButton" class="subput" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

This will refresh your page after form submit and form values will not be resubmitted.