# How to properly URL redirect in WordPress after form submission?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

How do I properly redirect after a form submission in WordPress? I truly have searched for it all over the place and have not yet found an answer to this. I think a good explanation to this question might benefit many.

In my case, I have a form that submits to itself, if the form validates, the data is saved and the user should be redirected. In case it fails, the user should see an error or be redirected depending on the nature of the error.

After researching, the most proper way seems to be to use the function `wp_redirect()`, but I can't get it to work. I know why, because the header has already been sent out ( meaning, browser has started to output and can't redirect). I got that part. But then, how do I use this function properly? I can't wrap my head around this one.

I tried using the good old `header(Location: http://www.example.com/);` response. No luck with that either.

Can anyone elaborate on this? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you mean header **response**, not *request*?

Comment: maybe try to use js. Somethin like this function redirect() { window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com" } and then call this function

Comment: toothbrush yes, response. @yuyokk, yes, that could be done with JS, however, there should be a way to do this with WP core functions. I am sure it is no rocket science, I just haven't figured out yet. Thanks though.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486701/wordpress-form-redirect-after-submit

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21843830/clear-form-after-submit-and-page-refresh-wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices:

- Write [your own plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin), and do the validation, and redirect from there if there was no error, or set the error if there was
- Write it in the `functions.php` and do it in the `init` state.

To write your own plugin, is a little bit more complicated, but not so hard, if you can programming.

If you do not want to do this, you need to do something like this, in your `functions.php` (This `functions.php` is in your theme directory. If there is no file like this, just create one.

Action on `init` is always happens, when all important wordpress files are loaded, but there was no output in the buffer, so you can use `header();` or `wp_redirect();` here.

```
add_action('init', 'myInit');
function myInit() {
    if (isset($_POST["mysubmit"])) {
        $errors = myFormValidation();
        if (empty($errors)) {
            //Do whatever you want here 
            header("Location: yoururl.php");
            die();
        }
        //Set the errors here
    }
}

function myFormValidation() {
    $errors = array();
    //do your validation here. check wordress documentation how to do this.
    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: Sweet @lolka_bolka! Thanks! I have to give this a shot some time today. Yes, I am writing my own plugin -- I'm just having problems with URL redirect. I think my problem is that I get confused when things are loaded within WP. So I should process all my form submissions in the `init` hook to handle URL redirection in case I need it? Is this the proper way to go about it?

Comment: Ok, that works great! You are the man! I totally understand how to implement this now from now on, it is supper easy! Just a reminder for those with this issue, place your `function myInit()` in your function.php or plugin file -- it will not work if you place it in a template file.

Comment: For those with the same issue again, you might want to consider to hook this action like this `add_action('template_redirect', 'myInit');` so you can use conditional tags. I.e. `is_page('login')`